# Interpretando XML com JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

Fiz um script com JQuery para utilizar AJAX e está funcionando. O problema é na hora de interpretar o XML é retornado, o XML é o resultado de uma tentativa de login, ele contém informações indicando se o usuário foi autenticado ou não, caso não, ele contém uma descrição de erro:

```
<result id='0 ou 1'>erro caso exista ou fica vazio</result>
```

Mas na hora de ler isso:

```
success: function(data){
                var s = $(data).find("result").each(function(){

                    var id = $(this).attr('id');

                    if(id == 0){
                        var error = $(this).text();
                        $(".error_description").text(error);
                        $(".error_description").css(display:"block");
                    }
                    else{
                        $(window.document.location).attr('href', "/Snotes/user_panel.php?id=" + id);
                    }
                });
            }
```

O código foi inspirado nos tutoriais de diversos posts na web, mas não está funcionando, e agora que o Google Chrome não quer mais parar nos *breakpoint* dentro da função `each`, fica mais difícil.

Comment: `$(".error_description").css(display:"block");` isso foi um erro de digitação ao escrever a pergunta, ou seu código está desse jeito mesmo? (faltou as chaves: `css({display:"block"})`) Além disso, na condição de sucesso o `action` é desse jeito mesmo, ou você não quis dizer `$("#go")[0].action`? (i.e. esse atributo - que não conheço - é do objeto jQuery ou do elemento DOM?)

Comment: Corrigido, o ("#go") eu achei na web, um método de redirecionamento, é assim mesmo

Comment: hmm, parece que o #go deve ser na verdade um elemento da página html, já modifiquei lá também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `$.parseXML()`

**Html**

```
<div id="id">id: </div>
<div id="texto">Texto: </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var xml = "<result id='0 ou 1'>erro caso exista ou fica vazio</result>";
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
$xml = $(xmlDoc).contents();
$("#id").append($xml.attr("id")); // adiciona "0 ou 1" à div
$("#texto").append($xml.html()); // adiciona "erro caso exista ou fica vazio" à div
```

Como você pode ver funcionando neste [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/44zP8/).

Comment: Funcionou agora, agradeço a ajuda.